# How to execute a specific function if a field is modified in Odoo 8?

Tags: triggers, odoo, odoo-8

I am working with the `product.product` object. It has a field named `qty_available`, which indicates the available quantity of the product in stock, as its name says.

Normally, I would add an `@api.depends('qty_available')` decorator to the method I want to be executed. But I think this method will not be executed unless I create a computed field which calls it. The problem is that the field `qty_available` can be modified from a lot of different views, and it would be very uncomfortable to modify each of those views to add the computed field.

Is there any way to do this rightly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do that when writing and no creating, you can re-define write function and check if that field is being writed.

```
@api.multi
def write(self, values):

    if values.get('qty_available'):

        #Your function here

    return super(ResPartner, self).write(values)
```

since values contains a dictionary with the fields that are being changed, it will run only if qty_available had change. Take care as this wont work if qty_available is a function field. In that case, you should overwrite that  function.

Comment: I was looking for complex ways and I did not think about a simple ORM overwrite, this is the best workaround. Thanks!